# OroCRM - How to use Symfony messenger component

Tags: orocrm, symfony-messenger

We use oro/crm version 4.1.0, in this version core team began to use symfony version 4.4.2 with symfony/symfony package (which includes symfony/messenger). But messenger component is not in use. For example, there is no  config/package/messenger.yml file, and I can't add messenger block to config.yml. Maybe I misread something, but how can I connect and use this component?

Answer (score 0):

This dependency was added automatically with symfony/symfony, but it's not used at all.

In ORO, there is an [own message queue component](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/mq/).

We'll consider requiring specific packages instead of a full symfony/symfony to remove the confusion. Thank you for the report!